# Java: sharing a vector between 2 classes

Tags: java, vector

I'm writing an application that calculates delta and roots of a second degree equation, accepting its coefficients as input. Later, i want to give it a GUI.

This is the class that calculates everything:

```
package functions;

import java.util.*;

public class Calculate implements Runnable {
double a=0;
double b=0;
double c=0;
double delta = 0;
double r1=0;
double r2=0;
Vector data=new Vector ();

public Calculate (Vector v) {
    synchronized (data) {
        synchronized (v) {
            data = v;
        }
        a =(double) data.elementAt(0);
        b =(double) data.elementAt(1);
        c =(double) data.elementAt(2);
    }
}
public double calcDelta () {
    delta = b*b-4*a*c;
    return delta;
}
public double root1 () {
    r1 = (-b+Math.sqrt(delta))/(2*a);
    return r1;
}
public double root2 () {
    r2 = (-b-Math.sqrt(delta))/(2*a);
    return r2;
}
public void createData (Vector z) {
    synchronized (z) {
        while (z.size()!=0) {
            z.removeElementAt(0);
        }
        z.add(delta);
        z.add(r1);
        z.add(r2);
    }

}
public void run () {
    calcDelta();
    root1 ();
    root2 ();
    //try {
        createData (data);
    //} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}
}
```

which i tested and is working well. The problem is in the test code i wrote for it:

```
import java.util.*;

import functions.*;

public class Test {
double a=0;
double b=0;
double c=0;
Vector v = new Vector ();
public Test (double arturo, double bartolomeo, double cirinci) {
    a=arturo;
    b=bartolomeo;
    c=cirinci;
    synchronized (v) {
        v.add(a);
        v.add(b);
        v.add(c);
    }
}
public Vector makevector () {
    return v;
}
public static void main (String [] args) {
    double art = (double) Integer.parseInt (args[0]);
    double bar = (double) Integer.parseInt (args[1]);
    double car = (double) Integer.parseInt (args[2]);

    Test t = new Test (art, bar, car);

    Thread launch;
    Vector data = t.makevector();
    Calculate res = new Calculate (data);
    launch = new Thread (res);

    launch.start();

    if (data.size()!=0) {
        System.out.println ("Delta: "+data.elementAt(0));
        System.out.println ("Radice 1: "+data.elementAt(1));
        System.out.println ("Radice 2: "+data.elementAt(2));
    }
}
}
```

and specifically in the output for Delta. In facts, roots are correctly shown, but instead of delta, it prints the a coefficient (by example, if i pass 1 1 -6, i expect delta to be 25, but it shows 1; if it s 2 2 -12 delta hould still be 25, but it shows 2).
Somehow, the first element of this vector doesn't get deleted and replaced, but i don't know why; i just know it's not a matter of synchronisation, since i tried to delete all of the syncs and the output was the same.

So, what's my mistake? Thank you.

Comment: It seems you've picked up a book from 1999 to learn Java. Java has evolved a lot since then. Vector shouldn't be used anymore. And collections are generic. Use an `ArrayList<Double>`. Or even better, define a class SecondDegreeEquation, containing 3 fields of type double: a, b and c.

Comment: Make it immutable. Don't store the result of a computation in the structure containing its inputs. And don't expect to have the answer as soon as you have started a thread. Threads execute in parallel. Frankly, you should learn the basis of Java and OO before dealing with threads, which are a complex matter.

Comment: Yes, i think my guide is pretty old; this code is similar to an example i found there; it looks like it's not only old, but terribly wrong to discuss about thread at that point...

Answer (score 0):

#### What's the point of all the multi-threading stuff ?

```
synchronized (data) {
```

This synchronize an object that you'll never use later

```
launch.start();
if (data.size()!=0) {
```

You don't even wait the thread to finish before using the data, try to add `join`

```
launch.start();
launch.join();
if (data.size()!=0) {
```

I suggest you first build an application that works without the threading stuff, then add multi-threading from that point.

#### I think it's a bad practice to have the same object hold the input and the output

The vector that you pass in the constructor is the same than the one you're expecting the result from. I think, inside `Calculate`, you should have another vector to hold the result, and when the thread has finished, access the result like:

```
launch.getResult()
```

#### Some code improvements

```
Vector data=new Vector ();
//...
data = v;
```

the vector created on the first line is never used. `data = v` doesn't copy each values from v into data. You can use:

```
data.addAll(v);
```

---

```
while (z.size()!=0) {
    z.removeElementAt(0);
}
```

Better do `z.clear();`

Comment: It was an example from my book, to show how threads work. Now i know how they do not work instead, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is (probably) that the calculations haven't finished before you print them.

Take a look at this part of your code:

```
launch.start();

if (data.size()!=0) {
    System.out.println ("Delta: "+data.elementAt(0));
    System.out.println ("Radice 1: "+data.elementAt(1));
    System.out.println ("Radice 2: "+data.elementAt(2));
}
```

When you do launch.start() the calculations start but in other thread, and this thread is still runing, so it starts to print the elements of data Vector. And those elements weren't updated yet.

Try adding `Thread.sleep(2000);` before the `if (data.size()!=0)` and see if the results change to what you would expect. This way you will make one thread to finish it's job before the other one prints the output.
This is not the solution of course - it will only show where the problem lies. If you want a solution look at java.util.concurrent and there you can finds something useful like CoundDownLatch.

Moreover you're using the `synchronized` keyword much to often and not necessarly proper. You should be always careful with using `synchronized`. 
Try this book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601)

but keep in mind that concurrency in Java is quite advanced subject.

Comment: No...even more confusing now. After adding a join () or sleep (2000), now it returns the coefficients instead of the results; the Calculate class still works. Oh well, i suppose i'll try to read more basic (and recent) guides before trying yours, even if this problem gets solved. Thank you anyways.

Comment: @daniele-squalo I tried your code with ```Thread.sleep(2000);``` or ```launch.join();```, both worked. I got [25,2,-3] when I input [1,1,-6]

Comment: There must have been some undesired line i forgot to delete, or while deleting some mistake i destroyed something good; after getting back the code from this topic and adding a join () it looks like you're right. Well, thanks to you i just spared some time and i can learn more now.